# Installing gogs with docker-compose

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gogs

I need to install the GIT-server Gogs as a service in docker-compose. This is quite easy using:

```
services:
  gogs:
    image: gogs/gogs:latest
    ports:
      - "10022:22"
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - "RUN_CROND=true"
    volumes:
      - "app-pool-gogs-data:/data"
```

In order to work with Gogs the installation has to be completed using the browser (select database, enter user credentials,...).

How to finish Gogs setup for a Sqlite3 database without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/slupekdev/gogs-docker-compose. You can also execute

```
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:3000/install' \
-H 'Origin: null' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
-H 'Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
-H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.221947403.1432575239; lang=fr-FR; i_like_gogits=4e8b96e2a97347e0; _csrf=0NHae8OjPYKJ6xiplpZcsUhkwu86MTQ0MTExMTA2MDEyMzQ4ODk0Ng%3D%3D' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
--data 'db_type=MySQL&db_host=mysql%3A3306&db_user=mgreau&db_passwd=mgreaudocker&db_name=gogs&ssl_mode=disable&db_path=data%2Fgogs.db&app_name=Gogs%3A+Go+Git+Service&repo_root_path=%2Fhome%2Fgit%2Fgogs-repositories&run_user=git&domain=192.168.99.100&ssh_port=22&http_port=3000&app_url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.99.100%3A3000%2F&smtp_host=&smtp_from=&smtp_email=&smtp_passwd=&admin_name=&admin_passwd=&admin_confirm_passwd=&admin_email=' --compressed
```

where 192.168.99.100 is your docker HOST IP

Answer (score 1):

You can place a predefined `api.ini` into `gogs/conf/` of your Gogs instance to bypass interaction with web UI during first-time access. There are many ways it can be done: by `COPY` in Dockerfile or by a setup script.

My solution is: https://github.com/symfony-doge/gogs-docker-compose